# In asp.net-mvc, How can I insert a class name from my view model for a html.dropdownlistfor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, html.dropdownlistfor

I have the following code in my view:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(r=>r.Id, Model.MyList, new { @class = "Dropdown hidden" })%>
```

but now I want to only assign the class "hidden" in certain cases so I want to pass that in from my ViewModel to either add the class or to leave it out.

To solve this, I created  a property in my view model called **HiddenConditional**

```
  public string HiddenConditional
  {
      get
      {
          return IfCondition() ? "hidden" : string.empty;
      }
  }
```

but i can't figure out the right syntax to put that into the class attribute.  I need something like:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(r=>r.Id, Model.MyList, new { @class = "Dropdown <%=Model.HiddenConditional%>" })%>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking too simply, but couldn't you set a property in the ViewModel to true or false, then in the DropDownListFor, do this:

`<%= Html.DropDownListFor(r=>r.Id, Model.MyList, new { @class = "Dropdown " + (Model.MyListIsHidden ? " hidden" : "") })%>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(r=>r.Id, Model.MyList, 
               new { @class = "Dropdown " + Model.HiddenConditional })%>
```

Comment: @leora Sorry I had just missed off the conditional, try the above.

Answer (score 1):

You may be tied to your solution of using `HiddenConditional` in your ViewModel, but I think it would be better to keep the class name in your View and simply use a boolean in your ViewModel. So it would look like this:

**ViewModel**

```
public bool MyListIsHidden { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(r=>r.Id, Model.MyList, new { @class = "Dropdown" + (Model.MyListIsHidden ? " hidden" : "") })%>
```